# Do SVGs embedded in CSS/SCSS data URIs still need to be base64 encoded?

Tags: css, svg

A while back, we started including SVGs as background-image css.  At the time, due to compatibility issues with IE we found just using SVGs as

`data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg ...> ... </svg>`

So we had to base64 them:

`data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL...`

Now that we have dropped support for IE < 11 does this still need to be done, or can I start simply using the SVG in the data URI as in the first example?

Comment: I think you should pay attention to some cases when using the first one. For example when it comes to HEX color, I know that Firefox will have some issue not reading them correctly.

Comment: Sitepoint article from Aug 2018 says it can be used: https://www.sitepoint.com/real-world-use-of-css-with-svg/

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's Chrome that processes # values incorrectly. I believe they are planning to change to match Firefox's correct implementation.

Comment: @RobertLongson but if I take this one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673218/8620333 .. it works fine on chrome but not firefox

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're looking at the issue in the wrong way. Chrome incorrectly displays your invalid document. Firefox correctly refuses to display your error filled content. There is however content that Firefox will display that Chrome cannot process correctly.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok got it, so I guess the answer is to better convert to base64 to be sure we won't fail into these cases.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Or you could use URL encoding correctly. The most commonly encountered character that requires encoding is #, most other characters remain the same after URL encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue the discussion from the comments:

A compromise that is both readable and shorter than base64 is to *URL encode* the SVG string, but with a few tricks to avoid encoding more than necessary. Here is a blog post explaining this technique:

https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris

..and tools to do the job:

https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/doMoML
https://github.com/tigt/mini-svg-data-uri

```
function specialHexEncode(match) {
    switch (match) { // Browsers tolerate these characters, and they're frequent
        case '%20': return ' ';
        case '%3D': return '=';
        case '%3A': return ':';
        case '%2F': return '/';
        default: return match.toLowerCase(); // Compresses better
    }
}

var result = svg
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')  // Collapse whitespace
    .replace(/"/g, "'");   // Swap quotes

result = encodeURIComponent(result)             // Encode everything..
    .replace(/%[\dA-F]{2}/g, specialHexEncode)  // ..except a few special characters

return 'data:image/svg+xml,' + result;
```

Comment: That article is from 2015.  That's why I have been asking if anything has changed lately. This is a cool method, but hardly worth the meager saving over base64.  Thanks.